# php folder does not exit on server

Tags: php, directory, vps, pydio

installed LAMP on my server , yet I am not able to view ajaxplorer on my server 162.243.5.155/ajaxplorer despite chmodding recursive to 777.Hover I am not also able to execute any php script at all,but I installed it properly.

Comment: This is not a question I have no idea ho I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access your folder by 162.243.5.155/ajaxplorer,  then check your public_html folder, it will have the ajaxplorer folder, if its not there, make sure you dont have any .htaccess redirects.

Comment: hello sir is it possible for you to configure it for me?<br>http://pastebin.com/FuusHCYc